# access child values from child gridspanels in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, telerik

Please help me how to access the child items in C#

```
<Grid Width="562" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="parentgrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="phara">
                <Grid x:Name="Pharamacygrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition></Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="115*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="447*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <Label Content="Name:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="lblName" Visibility="Visible" />
                    <ComboBox Height="23"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="Cmb_Name" Visibility="Visible" Width="120" DataContext="{StaticResource clientPharamcy}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="pharmacyName" SelectedValuePath="pharmacyName" SelectionChanged="Cmb_Name_SelectionChanged">  
                                 </ComboBox>
                    <Label Content="Address:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="lblAddress" Visibility="Visible" />
                    <TextBox Height="23" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="txtAddress" Visibility="Visible" Width="120" />
                    <Label Content="AdditionalAddress:" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="lblAdditionaladdr" Visibility="Visible" />
                    <TextBox Height="23" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="txtAdditionAddress" Visibility="Visible" Width="120" />
  </Grid> </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>  
    <telerik:RadDataForm AutoGenerateFields="False" Name="datform"
                         ReadOnlyTemplate="{StaticResource phara}"
                         EditTemplate="{StaticResource phara}" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Office_Black"
                         CommandButtonsVisibility="Cancel,Commit,Edit" EditEnded="datform_EditEnded" Margin="0,0,0,-82" />            
        </Grid>
```

Here i want access `Cmb_Name`, `txtAddress`, `txtAdditionAddress` in C# but they are not accessed in C# as they are in inner grid so please tell me how to access inner grids

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataTemplate` will be inflated and then added to the visual tree of 'datform'. Therefore, you can find these elements by recursively searching the visual tree using the `VisualTreeHelper` class.

**Proof of Concept Code:**

```
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Find all TextBox  visual children named "txtAddress" starting with the datform control
        var txtAddressMatches = GetVisualChildWithName("txtAddress", datform).OfType<TextBox>();

        // Fina all ComboBox visual children named "Cm_Name" starting with the datform control
        var Cmb_NameMatches = GetVisualChildWithName("Cm_Name", datform).OfType<ComboBox>();
    }

    private IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> GetVisualChildWithName(string name, FrameworkElement element)
    {
        return GetVisualChildWithName(name, element, new List<FrameworkElement>());
    }

    private IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> GetVisualChildWithName(string name, FrameworkElement element, IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> matches) 
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            return matches;
        }

        if (element.Name == name)
        {
            matches = matches.Concat(new []{element});
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            matches = matches.Concat(GetVisualChildWithName(name, VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement, new List<FrameworkElement>()));
        }

        return matches;
    }
```

The `VisualTreeHelper` class has static methods that allow you to discover all children and parent relationships for a given item (among other things). More information can be found here:

[MSDN on VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx)

Keep in mind that when walking the visual tree there is no guarantee of finding unique names, hence in the example code above I am returning a list of matches. This can happen for example if we had named elements in a `DataTemplate` being applied to each item in an `ItemsControl`. If we started searching the visual tree at the `ItemsControl` we would discover the named items in the template once for each container item (e.g. `ListBoxItem`).

Modifying the code above to have search depth would be trivial, but hopefully you get the idea :)